# Trying to create a ton of variables and a for loop won't work

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, scope, local-variables

So, I working on some JavaScript where I need to create a hundreds of variables that are going to hold URLs. I could make all of them in a for loop, but all of those variables would be local variables. Is there any way to make this work or any work arounds that I could possibly use?

Comment: Or an object whose property names are the names you would have given to all the variables.

Comment: Whats wrong with it being all local variables? Where do the urls come from in the first place

Comment: You can't create local variables dynamically in JS.

Comment: @putvande I wanted to initiate the variables within a for loop, and then use those variables outside the for loop.

Comment: @PhiladelphiaRegionalWeather Variables scope in JS is by function, so you can declare a variable in a loop and access it outside the loop.

Comment: @PhiladelphiaRegionalWeather can you show a quick example of your code? Someone will be able to translate it into an object or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @SLaks said, create an array variable outside of your for loop.  Push your url variables into the array as you create them. ex:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var url = "www.something.com";
    arr.push(url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you really saved me a lot of time and effort here!